# please how can l add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning

Tags: runtime-error, handlebars.js

I am creating a contact form that will display some messages on screen for the user to know that form was submitted successful
but,l am always receiving error message in my git terminal. Below is the error message.

Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "message" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details

Below is server.js and message.handlebars code;

```
app.post('/contactUs',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    //res.send('thanks');
    const newMessage = {
        fullname: req.body.fullname,
        email: req.body.email,
        message: req.body.message,
        date: new Date()
    }


    new Message(newMessage).save(function(err, message){
        if (err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            Message.find({}).then(function(messages){
                if(messages){                    
                    res.render('newmessage',{
                        title: 'Sent',
                        messages:messages
                    });
                }else{
                    res.render('noMessage',{
                        title: 'Not found'
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    });

});


<h1>Thank you for contacting</h1>
{{#each messages}}
<p>{{fullname}}</p>
<p>{{email}}</p>
<p>{{message}}</p>
<small>{{date}}</small>
<hr>
{{else}}
<p>No messages</p>
{{/each}}
<a href="/contact"><button class="btn btn-success">Contact Again</button></a>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing your doing the same dating app tutorial I am working on. I solved this problem by following the given link: https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access 
Then I downloaded the package npm install @handlebars/allow-prototype-access
Then in server.js add:

```
const express = require('express');
const Handlebars = require('handlebars')
const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const {allowInsecurePrototypeAccess} = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access')
```

Scroll down in server.js to app.engine:

```
    // setup view engine
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main',

}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Then add: `handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars)`

It should look like this:

```
// setup view engine
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main',
   handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars)
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

I hope this helps. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `.lean()` to your model for example `await Basic.findById(result.id).lean()`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31359813)

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because of the latest version of Handlebars, but this can be solved by adding a dependency to handlebars.

`npm i -D handlebars@4.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the exact same version of "express-handlebars" , which was shown in the tutorial. The latest version of handlebars is causing the problem.
Atleast doing this , worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Handlebars=require('handlebars')
const {allowInsecurePrototypeAccess} = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access')
app.engine('handlebars',exphbs({defaultLayout:'main',
handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars)
}));
app.set('view engine','handlebars');
```

this is happening to a new version of express-handlebars module. To fix this pass the following runtime options into handlebars engine configuration.
first of all, type a following command in your terminal and hit enter:

```
npm install @handlebars/allow-prototype-access
```

and

```
npm install handlebars
```

after that write these code into your server.js file

```
const Handlebars = require('handlebars')
```

and

```
const {allowInsecurePrototypeAccess} = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access')
```

then add this line:

```
handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars)
```

in your setup view engine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, pretty similar to the first answer:

```js
const express = require('express');
const handlebars = require('handlebars')
const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const { allowInsecurePrototypeAccess } = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access')

// configuration express for handlebars
app.engine('hbs', expressHandlebars({ extname: 'hbs', 
  defaultLayout: 'mainLayout', 
  handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(handlebars), 
  layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/' })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem while using mongoose with hbs, but I was using async / await instead of promises. So I tried .lean() method
like @Boniface Dennis said that solved my problem.
For more information please checkout [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html#using-lean)

```
//the syntax goes like this
const messages = await Messages.find({}).lean();
```